# I want to use a statement if value is X than Show popup "Time UP Please Order Tomorrow"

Tags: java, android

I want to add a function in my main activity that the application will fetch device time. If time is More than 2:00 PM in Device time or Less than 08:00 AM in Device time. A Popup will show after splash screen "Sorry Time UP, Please Order Tomorrow from 08:00 AM to 02:00 PM". And an Ok button to exit the application.

After Answer I Updated my Splash Activity. And nothing happened. 
 `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    // **************** ORDER SLOT ******************* //
    Calendar finalTime = Calendar.getInstance();

    Calendar mCalendarOpeningTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendarOpeningTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
    mCalendarOpeningTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    mCalendarOpeningTime.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

    Calendar mCalendarClosingTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendarClosingTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendarClosingTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);
    mCalendarClosingTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    mCalendarClosingTime.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);


    if (finalTime.after(mCalendarOpeningTime)&&finalTime.before(mCalendarClosingTime)){
        // show the dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreen.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setMessage("Order Full, Please Order Tomorrow before 02:00PM")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are too many ways to do this. If you want to get time from the internet you can use [TrueTime](https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android). As per your request, You can use `Date` instances :

```
 private void setOpeningAndClosingTimes() {
        //current time
        Calendar finalTime = Calendar.getInstance();

        Calendar mCalendarOpeningTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        mCalendarOpeningTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);
        mCalendarOpeningTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        mCalendarOpeningTime.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

        Calendar mCalendarClosingTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        mCalendarClosingTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        mCalendarClosingTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 2);
        mCalendarClosingTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        mCalendarClosingTime.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);




       if (finalTime.after(mCalendarOpeningTime)&&finalTime.before(mCalendarClosingTime)){
       // show the dialog

        Toast.makeText(this,"Time is 8Am to 2PM",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setMessage("Order Full, Please Order Tomorrow before 02:00PM")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
    }
```

Now call this method in `onCreate()` or `onStart()` so that the values are assigned to the respective "times" before you start using them: